# UIProgressView scaling issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm having this odd issue with UIProgressView. This video will explain better than I can with words...

https://vimeo.com/45399884 **password: stackoverflow**

But basically, I have a UIProgressView that uses iOS5's new setProgress:animated method. I'm animating it but when it animates, the slider part of the control is being scaled from the view's bounds 0,0 to bounds.size.max,bounds.size.max. It animates from left to right properly (with one exception), but scales at the same time. So basically it looks like a diagonal slide.

This is every bit of my progress view code.

```
progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 11)];
[self.view addSubview:progressView];
[progressView setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
[progressView setProgress:refreshInterval animated:YES];
```

Any tips or advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jason. I didn't even know about that aspect of this site. I went back to all of my questions and finished up the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designated initializer for `UIProgressView` is `-initWithProgressViewStyle:`. You're not supposed to modify the height of a progress bar, and while the height of the bar-style progress bar is 11, there are probably some effects being initialized in `-initWithProgressViewStyle:` that you're missing since the default height for the control is 9.

Comment: Ah right. Silly mistake on the init. Changing it to...

progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    [progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 11)];
    [self.view addSubview:progressView];
    [progressView setProgress:refreshInterval animated:YES];

... makes the track and progress bars both scale from left to right :)

Comment: @crewshin Yeah, it looks like it's a bug when you manually create and add a progress view and use that animate method. You should definitely report it to apple.

Answer (score 0):

The designated initializer for a `UIProgressView` appears to be `-initWithProgressBarStyle:`. Try creating it using that method.